# sizing image based on screen size and making it compatible with all browsers without scrolling or javascript

Tags: html, css, image, screen, screen-resolution

This is what I have so far for rendering an image that's 800 x 534 pixels. So far I have it scaling properly for users with smaller screen sizes and I am able to set a maximum image size for larger screen sizes.

I'm just curious as to how to modify this code so it works with as many browsers as possible, If there's an innerwidth or innerheight option I could use without relying on javascript then I'd go for that.

The reason I ask is because when I scale the image on the small screen, I still have to scroll the page about the same number of pixels as the height of the browser decorations regardless of which browser I use, and I want to avoid the requirement to scroll to see the whole image.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
    IMG {width: 100%;height: auto; max-width:800px; max-height:534px;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="image.jpg" width=800 height=534>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So if height of image > height of window you don't want scroll to show?

Comment: thats right. ditto for width

Answer (score 0):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/10/

CSS

```
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100vw;
}
```

If your image is fixed size find on what window size it goes to scroll and use media queries to fix it.